# How to create a chart from data in wide format in Tableau

Tags: formatting, data-visualization, tableau-api

**Background and objective**

I have data that is organised as follows:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|  Place              |      Time_Car    |       Time_Jet      |    Time_Heli    
|                     |                  |                     |              
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          LocX       |         34       |          12         |         14       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          LocY       |         24       |          8          |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

In Tableau, I want to be able to plot the average of the maximum times for each `Destination` column, for each type of transport.

So,

- For Time_heli, the maximum time to LocX is 8 (out of 7 and 8)
- The maximum time to LocY is 5
- The average of those two is 6.5

This produces something this after repeating for Time_car and Time_jet:
[image]

I am using Tableau 10.5.4 version on Windows 8

**Approach**

To do, I will get the maximum times for each Place by creating a new field for each type of transport with:

`{FIXED Place,Option: MAX([Time_Car])}`

`{FIXED Place,Option: MAX([Time_Jet])}`

`{FIXED Place,Option: MAX([Time_Heli])}`

However, this won't allow me plot the data in one chart on Tableau.

***How can I achieve the chart above?***

Comment: Read about the measure names and measure value placeholder fields in the online help

Comment: Your posted sample data doesn’t match the problem description. The numbers mentioned in your text description after the word “So”, 5, 7, 8, for instance - don’t show up in your table. It would be easier to describe a solution with a sample data set that matched the description, and that had a few data rows per location.